# django test runner do not see tests on py2 version, but see them on py3

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

When I run a command on `py3`:

```
python manage.py test myproject.user_management --settings mysettings.py
```

I see all my tests working fine:

> Ran 29 tests

But the same command on `py2`:

> Ran 0 tests

Command on `py2` is only working when I add `tests` folder to command, like:

```
python manage.py test myproject.user_management.test --settings mysettings.py
```

I already:
1. Double check my imports an `__init__.py` in all folders and sub folders
2. Settings etc.

My app structure looks like:

```
project_name
----user_management
--------__init__.py
--------tests
------------__init__.py
------------training
----------------__init__.py
----------------training.py
```

In `python manage.py shell` I can easy do:

`from myproject.user_management.tests import TrainingViewSetTest`

This behaviour happens only for few apps in my project.

Comment: Does the filenames of your tests start with `test*`?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this structure for using the default Django test runner:

```
user_management/
   __init__.py
   tests/
       __init__.py
       test_training.py
```

It should be able to find your tests in both versions now.

With that said, over the years I've started to put all of my tests in a root `tests/` directory, and use the following pytest configuration to find those tests `(setup.cfg)`:

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = --reuse-db --ds=settings.test
python_files =
    tests/integration/*.py
    tests/functional/*.py
test_paths =
    tests/
```

This has the benefit of quick test collection as well (not searching many directories and analyzing many files inside Docker on MacOSX!)